# VBA Checking a textbox value against multiple conditions

Tags: vba, multiple-conditions

I am trying to test the value of a text box against multiple conditions in VBA and am unsure of the best way to go about it.

The user is supposed to be entering a product ID and that ID can be in one of 5 formats and certain lengths depending on that format. Four of the 5 are alphanumeric (10) and the fifth is numeric only (13). For three of them (type A),I have it checking for the first few characters of the string to see if they match as anything after the first 2 are fair game. For Type B (numeric only) I have a number range set for that one and and trying to force the 13 digit length. For Type C it can start with LMN or LMNZZ and the rest of the characters should be digits.

Here is what I have so far...

```
Dim ALen, Blen, Clen as Integer
Dim val_UpperLimit,val_LowerLimit as Double

val_UpperLimit = 9999999999999#
val_LowerLimit = 100000000000# (Only 12 digits b/c # can start with 0)
ALen = "10"
BLen = "13"
CLen = "14"

'Check for Product Type B (Should be numeric value only. 13 digits long)
If IsNumeric(txtProduct.Value) _
    And txtProduct.Value < val_UpperLimit _
    And txtProduct.Value > val_LowerLimit _
    And Len(txtProduct.Value) = BLen _

    'Check for Product Type A (Product will start with A0, D0 or YY and be 10 characters long)
    Or txtProduct.Value Like "A0*" _
        And Len(txtProduct.Value) = ALen _
    Or txtProduct.Value Like "D0*" _
        And Len(txtProduct.Value) = ALen _
    Or txtProduct.Value Like "YY*" _
        And Len(txtProduct.Value) = ALen _

    'Check for Product Type C (Product will start with LMN# or LMNZZ# and be a total of 14 characters/digits)
    Or txtProduct.Value Like "LMN*" _
    Or txtProduct.Value Like "LMNZZ*" _
        And Len(txtProduct.Value) = CLen _
Then
    txtProduct.Value = UCase(txtProduct.Value)
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid Product ID", vbOKOnly
    txtProduct.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use a function as follows:

```
...

    If ProductIDIsValid(txtProduct.Value) Then
        txtProduct.Value = UCase(txtProduct.Value)
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid Product ID", vbOKOnly
        txtProduct.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

...

Public Function ProductIDIsValid(ByVal ProductID As String) As Boolean

    If Len(ProductID) = 10 And (Left(ProductID, 2) = "A0" Or Left(ProductID, 2) = "D0" Or Left(ProductID, 2) = "YY") Then 'Type A
        ProductIDIsValid = True
    ElseIf Len(ProductID) = 13 And Not ProductID Like "*[!0-9]*" Then 'Type B
        If CDbl(ProductID) >= 100000000000# Then ProductIDIsValid = True
    ElseIf Len(ProductID) = 14 And Left(ProductID, 3) = "LMN" Then 'Type C
        ProductIDIsValid = True
    Else 'No match
        ProductIDIsValid = False
    End If

End Function
```

So you can store that function in a module somewhere and call it as I did in the code.